# How to do authentication in django using OpenId keycloak?

Tags: django-rest-framework, keycloak

I want to do authenctication in django using KeyCloak, For this i had created a client in keyCloak and generated a clientid & json format, now how i have to exatcly get into it(i.e, how tokens are created?, how verification is done?). i have gone through so many codes but i am not undersatnding,soI want to know end to end flow